# Update Array of JLabels within a JPanel with GridLayout 5x5

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, label

Basicaly i got a JPanel with a GridLayout 5x5 and each "square" as a JLabel with a number and a diferent background color, depending on the number that its there.

I need to update the panel everytime i click one of the buttons (except menu one) because it will change the array of array of ints that is where i get the numbers from to put in the labels.

My Question is how do i update every JLabel (including color)
[JFrame Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q7mB.png)

```
public static JPanel painel(){
    novo_jogo();
    // Painel Grelha
    JPanel grelha = new JPanel();
    GridLayout grid_grelha = new GridLayout(linhas, colunas, 3, 3);
    grelha.setLayout(grid_grelha);
    grelha.setOpaque(true);
    grelha.setSize(janela_x - 140, janela_y-140);
    grelha.setLocation(70, 20);
    grelha.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    // criar JLabels
    for (int num = 0; num < linhas; num++){
        for (int num2 = 0; num2 < colunas; num2++){
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setText(String.valueOf(tabuleiro[num][num2]));
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(select_cor(tabuleiro[num][num2]));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            grelha.add(label);
        }
    }
    return grelha;
```

this is the function that creates the entire panel in the proper grid etc...
(This is also made in a diferent class that extends from the main one

```
public class Board extends Game{....}
```

my idea was to use the repaint() function to update only the panel with the grid`JPanel grelha = Board.painel();` and then `frame.getContentPane().add(grelha);`
later my idea was to update the grid (grelha) panel only but when i do this:

```
/* Main */
public static void main(String[] args){
    frame.setTitle("Jogo 2048 em Java"); // Titulo da janela
    frame.setSize(janela_x, janela_y); // Define o tamanho da janela
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Centraliza a janela no ecrã
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setResizable(false); // Não deixa a janela ser aumentada
    // Painel Fundo
    JPanel fundo = new JPanel();
    fundo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    // Painel Botões
    JPanel botoes = new JPanel();
    GridLayout grid_botoes = new GridLayout(1, 5, 5, 5);
    botoes.setLayout(grid_botoes);
    botoes.setOpaque(true);
    botoes.setSize(360, 50);
    botoes.setLocation(70, 390);
    botoes.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    JPanel grelha = Board.painel();
    // Botões e colocar no painel
    JButton init = new JButton("Init");
    JButton left = new JButton("Left");
    JButton down = new JButton("Down");
    JButton right = new JButton("Right");
    JButton menu = new JButton("Menu");
    botoes.add(init);
    botoes.add(left);
    botoes.add(down);
    botoes.add(right);
    botoes.add(menu);
    // Adicionar Panels à janela
    frame.getContentPane().add(botoes);
    frame.getContentPane().add(grelha);
    frame.getContentPane().add(fundo);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    // ActionListener dos botões
    ActionListener accao_botoes = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int n = -1;
            if (e.getSource().equals(init)) n = 0;
            else if (e.getSource().equals(left)) n = 1;
            else if (e.getSource().equals(down)) n = 2;
            else if (e.getSource().equals(right)) n = 3;
            else n = 4;
            switch (n){
                case 0:
                    Board.novo_jogo();
                    Board.print();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Board.esquerda();
                    Board.print();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Board.baixo();
                    Board.print();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Board.direita();
                    Board.print();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    janela_menu();
                    break;
                }
        }
    };
    init.addActionListener(accao_botoes);
    left.addActionListener(accao_botoes);
    down.addActionListener(accao_botoes);
    right.addActionListener(accao_botoes);
    menu.addActionListener(accao_botoes);
    while(true){
        frame.repaint();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

it doesnt update the panel, infact it doesnt update anything :(
i tryed grelha.validate(), grelha.repaint() and nothing seems to work, am i missing anything?

Anyone can help me?

Comment: first - I can't see `frame.setVisible(true);`
second - when you suppose to update the frame?

Comment: i updated the code to include all my main

Comment: Im supposed to update the Labels everytime i click one of the buttons (except menu button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create Board instance and keep reference to this object
   `Board board=Board.painel();`
2. operate on that instance
   `board.direita(); board.print();`
3. inplementataion of direita in class Board should change JLabel properties
4. remove `while(true)` loop. EDT will update swing widgets.

Example of `direita` (other movings make in similar way)

```
public void direita() {
    if (currentX+1 < colunas) ++currentX;
    JLabel label = labels[currentY][currentX];
    label.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

Example of `painel`

```
public static Board painel(){
    // Painel Grelha
    return new Board();
}
```

and `Board` constructor

```
public Board() {
    GridLayout grid_grelha = new GridLayout(linhas, colunas, 3, 3);
    setLayout(grid_grelha);
    setOpaque(true);
    setSize(janela_x - 140, janela_y-140);
    setLocation(70, 20);
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    // criar JLabels
    for (int num = 0; num < linhas; num++){
        for (int num2 = 0; num2 < colunas; num2++){
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            //label.setText(String.format("%d,%d",num,num2));
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(select_cor(num,num2));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            add(label);
            labels[num][num2]=label;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Board board = Board.painel(); doesnt allow me, since painel return a JPanel, shall i change board to a JPanel? or change the return type of painel() to Board?

Comment: also, the Board.print is just a textual representation of the array of ints that i got at the moment: prntscr.com/bb6nk9

Comment: when u say "inplementaion of direita in class Board should change JLabel properties" u mean that i must execute the "painel()" function on the "direita()" function on the board? Sorry if i am very noob at this, its my first time working on swing :/

Comment: No, I said `direita` as en example. Each of them (`direita`, `recta`,...) should just implement seting properties of the label at right `(row,col)` position.
so for example `direita` code find in my edited answer:

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bcwuv7, Tabuleiro is a array of array of ints, and i got a array of JLabels and that function updates all of them.

But thanks for help anyway :).

Comment: See, that you create JLabels every time.

Comment: not rly, i just make them 1 time, and then i update them the rest of the game

Comment: Oh yes, indeed! I missed it.